# Create and store the geo-location data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, geocode

I'm creating rails application where it allow users to add geo-location data for restaurants, shops, etc., to a (Google) map and query it.

First I started with http://geoapi.com, as there is a feature for creating our own entities and querying them. But the service doesn't support my country well. So, I decided to create and store the geo-location data on my own database.

Can someone please tell me what are the best gems/plugins available for this? 
I found these, but I'd like to get some feedback from you. Thanks

http://github.com/queso/ym4r-gm

http://github.com/andre/geokit-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend PostGIS and then use a Ruby Connector.

Comment: Can you explain why you prefer this over other options?  And do you just prefer it in general, or is it more appropriate for the purpose described for some reason.